# How to install ROS Melodic on Ubuntu 19.04?

Tags: software-installation, 19.04, ros

I am trying to install ROS Melodic on Ubuntu 19.04 and having done all the appropriate preparation I am using the command:

```
sudo apt install ros-melodic-desktop-full
```

and I get the following error:

```
Unable to locate package ros-melodic-desktop-full
```

Any thoughts about what I should do?

Comment: ROS Melodic is available to up Ubuntu 18.04 (Bionic) only. Installing in newer releases requires compiling from source, something really not recommended for someone posting a question like this, if you know what I mean ;)

Comment: And what should I do if I need to run ROS ? I mean I have a university task to do.

Comment: Either install a compatible Ubuntu release and follow the instructions as you did before or, keeping 19.04, download the ROS source code and compile according to the instructions inside.

Comment: Will use a VM instead but thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Melodic is not supported on 19.04. Target platforms are listed at: https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html

You can see the planned release schedule here: http://wiki.ros.org/Distributions#Release_Schedule

With the next release, noetic, planning going on here: https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/rep/pull/202/files

Related: https://answers.ros.org/question/322377/unable-to-install-ros-melodic-on-ubuntu-1904/